# Sketch image of of multivariable function on given set

Tags: calculus

For the function, $f(r,\theta)= (r\cos\theta , r\sin\theta )$, to sketch the image under $f$ of the set $S=[1,2]$ x$ 
[0,\pi]$

My first step was to find the images of $f$ by along the borders of the line segments given by the rectangle.  However, I am unsure of how to proceed to find the sketch of the entire image.  Below is what I got from fixing $r$, and $\theta$ on the bordering line segments

$$f(r,0)=(r,0)$$
$$f(r,\pi)=(-\pi,0)$$
$$f(1,\theta)=(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$$
$$f(2,0)=(2\cos\theta, 2\sin\theta)$$

Comment: You do remember from trigonometry what shape $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ is, don't you?

Comment: yup.  Wording of the question confused me for some reason and my sily computation errors, as can be seen above, caused me even more confusion.  I did receive a very thorough response which clarified the issue.  Here's the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462214/how-to-sketch-image-under-function-on-given-set